# Can't get ng-controller to work in ionic app

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

## edit: This questions is solved

Stupidly enough, the url /img/images.json is treated differently by the simpleHttpServer used to test the application than by the iOS simulator.

It was a long search why it would show the list in the browser when testing but not in the simulator. Apparently the simpleHttpServer that comes with python will treat a url starting with the / as it's root, for example the www folder. The simulator does not and would appreciate a relative location, starting with no /

The problem seems mostly caused by the rustiness of my web-dev skills ^.^

====================

I am trying to make a simple ionic app, and for some input I am using the Angular Tutorial.

I have a very simple page that should load the contents of a json-file with image data. And all it needs to do for now is showing the image names. At the end it should dump the complete data from the json-file.

This is all based of the blank project created with ionic.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="phocalsApp">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="imageListCtl">


        <ul class="imagelist">
          <li ng-repeat="image in imagelist" >
            {{image.imgName}}
          </li>
        </ul>
        {{imagelist | json}}
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('phocalsApp', ['ionic', 'phocalsControllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

controller.js

```
'use strict';

var phocalsControllers = angular.module('phocalsControllers', []);

phocalsControllers.controller('imageListCtl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/img/images.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.imagelist = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'imgDate';
  }]);
```

images.json:

```
[
    {
        "imgUrl":"",
        "imgName":"Nieuwste Foto",
        "imgDate":20140525
    },
    {
        "imgUrl":"",
        "imgName":"tweede Foto",
        "imgDate":20140524
    },
    {
        "imgUrl":"",
        "imgName":"derde Foto",
        "imgDate":20140523
    }
]
```

Seeing as I pretty much use the same code as the angular example, I would expect this to work, unfortunately all the output I am getting when running in the ios Simulator is an empty page with the header-bar. No errors or nothing. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

[image: Result in iOS emulator]

Comment: I stared at this for a while, and I can't see anything. Is it possible that some of the files failed to download?

Comment: If angular is not interpolating the expressions `{{imagelist | json}}`, it is typically because angular failed to bootstrap, often due to missing dependencies or a syntax error in the module declarations.

Comment: @starchild based on the code shown in the post, any Idea where I need to look? This is all the code I have so if there is a syntax error it should be in there.

Comment: Stupidly enough, the url /img/images.json is treated differently by the simpleHttpServer used to test the application than by the iOS simulator.

It was a long search why it would show the list in the browser when testing but not in the simulator. Apparently the simpleHttpServer that comes with python will treat a url starting with the / as it's root, for example the www folder. The simulator does not and would appreciate a relative location, starting with no / 

The problem seems mostly caused by the rustiness of my web-dev skills ^.^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some console.log(data) in your controller to check whether the controller is initialized, wether $http actually succeeds etc. 
Even after using angular for months, i have to log every step cause there are too many things to go wrong :)

Also you should add an error function to

```
$http.get('/img/images.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.imagelist = data;
}).error(function(data) ....;
```

Comment: This did point me in the right direction ^.^ I guess you've earned the 50 for help ending this 4 day search